# Using wrong library after linking 2 eclipse project Java

Tags: java, eclipse, gps

I am having trouble when linking the 2 projects in eclipse together.

I have project 1 (P1) which is transforming one set of coordinates in to other form.

`i.e. from EPSG:2326 to EPSG:4326`

and project 2 (P2) which is transforming from `EPSG:4326 to EPSG:2326`

The 2 projects need to use 2 different libraries in order to give accurate results.

However, when I add `P2` into `P1` build path by adding project in the tab.

After executing the projects, the results showed that `P2` is using `P1` library, which is the transform library, hence the result is not acceptable.

Question:

How to specify `P2` to use that particular library but not the `P1` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution i have reached is:
1. change all the stuff to maven, and add library dependency to it.
2. change the package names of its projects and it suddenly all fine!.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are having dependency issues. Something along the lines of:

1. `P1` **depends on** `Pa`
2. `P2` **depends on** `Pb`
3. When you make `P1` **depend on** `P2` you get an issue where both start to use `Pa/Pb` when you need them to remain separate as in (1) and (2)

The best solution to this would be to use a build tool like [ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) or [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). I would reccomend Maven. These would let you define which projects should explicitly use which. This will make it much easier to manage these sorts of issues.

**Note:** Eclipse has plugins for both of these tools which make it even easier to use. [Maven in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) and [Ant in Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/ant/)